# Create a "push down" effect in an activity feed with jQuery

Tags: jquery

so I am using JSON and jQuery to pull new activities into an activity feed. I'm looking for the latest entry to "push down" the formerly latest entry. Any tips much appreciated :D

The HTML structure of the feed:

```
    <div id="activityspot">
        <div class="entry template">
            <div class="actProfilePic"></div>
            <div class="actMessage"></div>
            <div class="actName"></div>
            <div class="actContent"></div>
            <div class="actImage"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The jQuery:

```
for (var j = 0; j < jsonData.items.length; j++) {
  var entryData = jsonData.items[j];
  var entry = template.clone();
  entry.removeClass("template");

  entry.find(".message").text(entryData.statusid); 
  entry.find(".actName").text(entryData.name); 
  entry.find(".actContent").text(entryData.content);

  //get the users ProfilePic
  var profileImg = $("<img />");
  profileImg.attr("src", "./img/" +entryData.profilePic);
  profileImg.addClass("feed-user-img");
  entry.find(".actProfilePic").append(profileImg);

  //Get user-uploaded images.
  entry.find(".actImage").text(entryData.imageKey);
  if (entryData.imageKey != "") 
        {
          var img = $("<img />"); // Create the image element
          img.attr("src", "http://spartadev.s3.amazonaws.com/" + entryData.imageKey); // Set src to the s3 url plus the imageKey
          entry.find(".actImage").append(img); // Append it to the element where it's supposed to be
        }
  spot.prepend(entry); //Finish off by prepending the new entry to the top of the feed
}
```

Comment: I tried using spot.prepend(entry).hide().fadeIn(); but that caused the entire #activityspot to fade in, instead of just the latest entry. Hmm!

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle ? It will be easier to help you. For the thing in your comment. Try `entry.css("visibility","hidden"); spot.prepend(entry); entry.fadeIn();` What you are doing here is hide spot and fade in spot, not entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spot.prepend(entry) returns the activityspot and hide and fadeIn will be applied to activityspot.

as you apply it to latest entry, first you have to select the latest entry and then apply hide and fadeIn like this

```
spot.prepend(entry);
spot.find(".entry.template").first().hide().fadeIn();
```

first() is called as you are prepending the element so assuming the latest entry is the first child element of activityspot of class "entry template"

Comment: That worked, thanks! It's a little bit clunky with the fadeIn - I might try slideDown too :)